# Remove lines from file in Linux, exact match

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I need to remove all lines containing "['@everyone']" using sed, grep or awk.

Example:

```
USER: user1 - (327287311424072921) - No - ['@everyone']
USER: user2 - (323639467155241152) - No - ['@everyone']
USER: user3 - (213739640403696966) - No - ['@everyone', 'OK']
USER: user4 - (211732640103626928) - No - ['@everyone', 'Group1']
```

Desired result:

```
USER: user3 - (213739640403696966) - No - ['@everyone', 'OK']
USER: user4 - (211732640103626928) - No - ['@everyone', 'Group1']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: share what you have tried to acheive this desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk '!/\[\047@everyone\047\]/' file
```

The output:

```
USER: user3 - (213739640403696966) - No - ['@everyone', 'OK']
USER: user4 - (211732640103626928) - No - ['@everyone', 'Group1']
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that `grep` with `-F` `-v` option should be the best choice. You don't care about those escapes...

```
grep -vF "['@everyone']" file
```

read `man grep` to get info, what does '-F / -v' mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with grep and negate the result. I don't know if you need to pipe it to grep or if you have a file. So here both versions.

```
cat file.txt|grep -v "\['@everyone'\]"
```

or

```
grep -v "\['@everyone'\]" test.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk 'NF>8' file

USER: user3 - (213739640403696966) - No - ['@everyone', 'OK']
USER: user4 - (211732640103626928) - No - ['@everyone', 'Group1']
```

The main point here, as I understand it, is to get rid of lines 
containing ['@everyone'] but that does not mean I have to point at it.
Becouse then I have to get single quote involved with its complications.

Thats why I did my very first proposal, another way is:

```
awk '!/user1|user2/' file
```

But if someone insists to have ['@everyone'] included you can put it like this:

```
awk '$8=="[\47@everyone\47,"' file
or
awk '$8 ~/\[\47@everyone\47,/' file
```

Both escaping single quote and the latter even the bracket.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, how exactly does this delete only lines containing `['@everyone']`, rather than simply those containing 7 or more whitespace blocks?